# android webview cookies not working

Tags: php, android, cookies, webviewclient

Setting an cookie using PHP doesn't work in Android Web-view. I've tried using the "CookieManager" manager and even tried setting cookie domain sever side. I'm out of idea on how to fix this.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
    WebView browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
    browser.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
    browser.loadUrl("url");
    browser.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    browser.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
}

private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try initializing your webview first and then calling `CookieManager.getInstance()` post loading the url.

`CookieManager.getInstance()` is the CookieManager at application level.